# error 404: relatively path did not found my @path paremeter in resteasy webservicers below example

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy

I have Item Class below

```
   @XmlRootElement(name = "item")  public class Item {

private String description;
private long price;//setter getter method }
```

Ans ItemList Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "listing") @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) @NoJackson
public class ItemList {
private List<Item> items;// getter mothod }
```

Service Class Of Item

```
@Path("user")   public class ItemService extends Application {
@GET
@Path("itemList")
@Produces("application/xml")
 public ItemList  getCollItems(@Context HttpServletRequest request)  {  
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();  
        Item item1 = new Item("computer",2500);  
        Item item2 = new Item("chair",100);  
        Item item3 = new Item("table",200);  

        list.add(item1);  
        list.add(item2);  
        list.add(item3);  

        return new ItemList(list);

}
```

}

Web.xml

```
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>com.service.ItemService</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Hear, I have write url :-** localhost:port/appNAME/**rest/user/itemList** it's not work properly but it will give error **HTTP Status 404 - /rest/user/itemList**

Please tell me what i actual missing....?

Comment: Try adding a leading slash to your @Path values.

Comment: @Zaki : thanks for help me but still its give an error :HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /user/itemList of full path: http://localhost:8085/RestTesting/rest/user/itemList